# how to identify rtmp packets of different video streams and audio streams

Tags: audio, video, networking, rtmp

The RTMP specification says - The packets of different videos and audios can be multiplexed and sent over the single connection. I want to know how we can distinguish between two RTMP packets so as to know to which video the packet corresponds to ?? For eg . Lets say we are sending two videos from our server namely - Video1 and Video2 . 
1.Now if the packets of both the videos are coming over the stream how can we know whether the packet belongs to Video1 or to Video2 ??

2. Now if the packet type is 3 then whose reference must be taken ? Reference of type 0 packet of Video1 stream or reference of type 0 packet of Video2 stream ?

First thing I want to make sure of is - Will there be two different connections for two videos (from the reference of client) ??

If yes , then can't I use the port number of the packet so obtained to identify to which video does the packet belong to ? Am I thinking right ??

Answer (score 0):

RTMP connection set only 1 time (1935 port). You can distinguish video streams by number of message_stream_id. Each  message_stream_id consist of chunks which can be assembled into a message. Each chunk is asociated with some message_stream_id.